# Scaling and High Availability of Oracle Database

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, scalability, high-availability

As per Oracle Docs we can use Oracle RAC for HA and scaling the database.

I see that Oracle RAC uses shared persistence ( SAN based) to share the Data ( data files, control files of DB) among the multiple instances http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HAOVW/architectures.htm#CHDBIJAJ.

But, at WebScale( Facebook kind of scale) the SAN is the bottleneck ( Any central point), right ? Also, It is the special hardware instead of commodity hardware and also single point of failure.

So, My questions are ,

**1.** Do we require Oracle RAC for HA and scale, Can we not setup scaling and HA without RAC using **standard Oracle Instances** with Master and Slave configurations ?

**2.** How can we make Oracle database instances ( each with **it's own disk for the DB data**) work with any of following

- Multi-master and slave configuration with synchronous two phase commit
- "Master and Slave configuration" with slave taking over master, in case master fails.
- The way **MySQL** does with "Multi-master" or "master and slave configurations".

**PS**: I couldn't find the answers on the web, So I think the answers will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a 'master/slave' configuration, you're looking at Oracle DataGuard which must be run on Enterprise Edition and is an extra cost ad-on.

DataGuard will essentially copy redo log data over to another server (in real-time) and update the data files on the 'slave' server.  DataGuard can also be configured so that the standby server is open for read-only queries.

It can handle the items you bullet out in your 2nd point.

Comment: But, to achieve High availability, How can we have multi-master ( may be with two phase commit ) ? 
Also, Is it possible to automatically take over Dataguard configured slave server in-case master is down ?

Comment: In its default configuration, data that's committed on the master database is committed within seconds (milliseconds) on the slave.  There are also configuration changes that can be made so that a user committing, won't get a 'commit OK' until commits have been made on both master and slave.

There are also automatic failover options so that control is passed to the slave database after detection of an issue on the master database.

Highly suggest you read a book such as Oracle's Data Guard Handbook which covers many scenarios. This can get complex.

Comment: For HA, you can also look into Oracle RAC...where you have multiple Oracle database servers pointing to a common data store.

Comment: But, I see problems with Oracle RAC as said in the main question.
Do you know the difference between Data Guard and GoldenGate ?
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html

Comment: Golden Gate is a replication add-on from Oracle that allows for multi-master and bi-directional replication.  There's lots of information about this on the Internet, [here's a comparison of Active Data Guard & Golden Gate](http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/dataguardgoldengate-096557.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: I am part of the Database Product Management team at Oracle.]

If you look deeper, you will find that Oracle RAC is designed a solution for database High Availability and Scalability. You are right in thinking that for such a shared storage solution the shared storage should become an issue and a key area of contention. However, if you look closely Oracle addresses that issue by using certain optimizations and technologies that are that were purposely developed. Oracle’s Exadata systems use Oracle RAC as the foundation for HA and Scalability.

I do not want to sound like promoting Oracle products, but here it may help to know that 87% of Fortune Global 100 use Exadata and that some of the world’s most mission critical workloads run on Exadata and use Oracle RAC. Please also see, [Oracle’s New Exadata X9M Looks Disruptive](https://www.forbes.com/sites/moorinsights/2021/09/28/oracles-new-exadata-x9m-looks-disruptive/?sh=907d05a3e6e4)

You can learn more about Oracle RAC through the documentation and by visiting https://www.oracle.com/database/real-application-clusters/

Comment: Stop promoting Oracle Product, This doesn't even address the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It did sound like promoting the product but I was simply drawing attention of the seeker to certain facts that may serve as a way to understand and realize that we actually recognize the basic problem here and have long ago addressed it in our product already. But after seeing your note, I have put down a disclaimer and also updated the answer. I do appreciate your note. Thank you again!